# php - get exact server timezone

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to get the exact timezone of my server (not PHP configured timezone).

I don't want to use: date_default_timezone_set() since I don't know what is my server's timezone (and don't want to know because it may change).

I tried these lines of codes which returned different date/times:

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` might be returning correct time but how can I return the timezone (not the date/time)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
system('date +%Z');
```

While that might do the job, it has some security implications, you don't want your app to reconfigure the server, but all you do is read.

It has its trade-offs. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how can I return something like "America/New_York" instead of EST (for example) to use in php codes like date_default_timezone_set?